# Sending messages from Shiny to JavaScript

Tags: javascript, r, shiny

I am trying to call a JavaScript function from Shiny each time when a tab of the app is clicked. I need to send a tab name to custom js function. As the simplest option I call `alert()` function from R and transfer to it the name of a tab. For some reason my code doesn't work and a window with a message doesn't appear although I’ve replicated the [example](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/js-send-message.html).

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinyjs)

ui = dashboardPage(

  dashboardHeader(title = "Shiny"),

  dashboardSidebar(
    sidebarMenu(id = "tabs",

                menuItem("Section_1", tabName = "section_1", icon = icon("align-justify"), 
                         startExpanded = TRUE, selected = TRUE,
                         menuSubItem("Subsection 1", tabName = "report_1", selected = TRUE),
                         menuSubItem("Subsection 2", tabName = "report_2")),
                menuItem("Section_2", tabName = "section_2", icon = icon("align-justify"))

    )
  ),

  dashboardBody(

    useShinyjs(),

    tags$head(tags$script("Shiny.addCustomMessageHandler('handler1', alert(tab_name))")),

    tabItems(
      tabItem("report_1", h1(id = "a", "a")),
      tabItem("report_2", h1(id = "b", "b")),
      tabItem("section_2", h1(id = "c", "c")))
  )
)


server <- function(input, output, session) {

  observe({ 

    if(input$tabs == "report_1") {
      print(input$tabs)
      tab_name = as.character(input$tabs)
      session$sendCustomMessage(type = "handler1", tab_name)
    } else if(input$tabs == "report_2"){
      print(input$tabs)
      tab_name = as.character(input$tabs)
      session$sendCustomMessage(type = "handler1", tab_name)
    } else if (input$tabs == "section_2"){
      print(input$tabs)
      tab_name = as.character(input$tabs)
      session$sendCustomMessage(type = "handler1", tab_name)
    }

  })
}

shinyApp(ui=ui, server=server)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Write a function inside the `addCustomMessageHandler` like so:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinyjs)

ui = dashboardPage(

  dashboardHeader(title = "Shiny"),

  dashboardSidebar(
    sidebarMenu(id = "tabs",

                menuItem("Section_1", tabName = "section_1", icon = icon("align-justify"), 
                         startExpanded = TRUE, selected = TRUE,
                         menuSubItem("Subsection 1", tabName = "report_1", selected = TRUE),
                         menuSubItem("Subsection 2", tabName = "report_2")),
                menuItem("Section_2", tabName = "section_2", icon = icon("align-justify"))

    )
  ),

  dashboardBody(

    useShinyjs(),

    tags$head(tags$script('Shiny.addCustomMessageHandler("handler1", function(message) {
                            alert(JSON.stringify(message));
                          })')),

    tabItems(
      tabItem("report_1", h1(id = "a", "a")),
      tabItem("report_2", h1(id = "b", "b")),
      tabItem("section_2", h1(id = "c", "c")))
  )
)


server <- function(input, output, session) {

  observe({ 

    if(input$tabs == "report_1") {
      print(input$tabs)
      tab_name = as.character(input$tabs)
      session$sendCustomMessage(type = "handler1", tab_name)
    } else if(input$tabs == "report_2"){
      print(input$tabs)
      tab_name = as.character(input$tabs)
      session$sendCustomMessage(type = "handler1", tab_name)
    } else if (input$tabs == "section_2"){
      print(input$tabs)
      tab_name = as.character(input$tabs)
      session$sendCustomMessage(type = "handler1", tab_name)
    }

  })
}

shinyApp(ui=ui, server=server)
```

[image]

Comment: Why don't you use only one `sendCustomMessage` ? `session$sendCustomMessage(type = "handler1", as.character(input$tabs))`. This would give the same result, no ?

Comment: I tried to be on par with https://shiny.rstudio.com/gallery/server-to-client-custom-messages.html

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent Thank you for idea for optimisation.

Comment: It could be also be worth mentioning this blog post: https://ryouready.wordpress.com/2013/11/20/sending-data-from-client-to-server-and-back-using-shiny/. Gives  a really good introduction.